# Tipos de breakpoints no Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, debug, ide, breakpoints

Acredito que muitos que utilizam ou já utilizaram o [eclipse](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_(software)) já notaram que existem diversos tipos de *breakpoints* existentes nele.

Os que possuem maior aparições são os semelhantes à este: <kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>, porém, vi que existem diversos tipos de ícones para *breakpoints*(não consegui encontrar imagens de todos) como <kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>, <kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>, <kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>, entre outros...

Acredito que cada uma possua sua particularidade dentro do *eclipse* e gostaria de saber quais são os tipos de *breakpoints* no *eclipse* e qual a diferença/utilidade de cada um deles?

Answer (score 1):

Ola

Não sei exatamente as imagens (porque acho que varia de versões), mas os tipos de break points que eu conheço são

1. Java Class Breakpoints - quando a classe for instanciada (pasta aberta com uma bolinha azul)
2. Java Exception Breakpoints - quando determinada excessão for lançada (Jota com exclamação)
3. Java Line Breakpoints - quando o debug passar em determinada linha (Jota com bolinha azul)
4. Java Method Breakpoints - quando determinado método for chamado (M)
5. Java Watchpoints - quando determianda condição for atingida (binóculo)

https://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftask-add_line_breakpoints.htm